# SearchController SearchBar width issue iOS11

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, swift4, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to add SearchController SearchBar programmatically in one of `UIVIew` as subView but initially it working properly up to iOS 10 but getting issue in iOS11 width getting increased get displaced.

I tried all possible solutions, Created Custom class init SearchBar frame with `CGRect.zero` & even hide cancel button. Still i does not understanding where I am doing wrong.

Initial Screen:

[image]

Issue is here when i clicked on SearchBar

[image]

Irony is its not working even i am trying to reset frame width to 100.0f by calling method `viewWillLayoutSubviews` from `searchBarShouldBeginEditing`

```
func setUpSearchBar(){
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

        resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
        resultsViewController?.delegate = self as GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate
        searchController = CustomSearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
        searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

        //resultsViewController?.view.frame = searchAndButtonView.bounds
        //let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 65.0, width: 350.0, height: 45.0))


         searchController?.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: searchView.frame.size.width, height: searchView.frame.size.height)

        searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchView.addSubview((searchController?.searchBar)!)

        searchView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        searchController?.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        definesPresentationContext = false

        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .top

    }
```

**CustomSearchController.swift**

```
class CustomSearchController: UISearchController,UISearchBarDelegate{

    let noCancelButtonSearchBar = NoCancelButtonSearchBar()

    lazy var _searchBar: NoCancelButtonSearchBar = {
        [unowned self] in
        let customSearchBar = NoCancelButtonSearchBar(frame: CGRect.zero)
        return customSearchBar
        }()

    override var searchBar: UISearchBar {
        get {
            return _searchBar
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}

class NoCancelButtonSearchBar: UISearchBar {
    override func setShowsCancelButton(_ showsCancelButton: Bool, animated: Bool) { /*
    void */ }

}
```

Comment: oK wait i will add the code.

Answer (score 2):

After lot of attempts i resolved issue by following way,

I removed customised CustomSearchController class & used simple `UISearchController` .

```
func setUpSearchBar(){
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

        resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
        resultsViewController?.delegate = self as GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
        searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController


         searchController?.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: searchView.frame.size.width, height: searchView.frame.size.height)

        let searchBarContainer = SearchBarContainerView(customSearchBar: searchController?.searchBar)  
        searchBarContainer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 44)
        searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchView.addSubview(searchBarContainer)

        searchView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        searchController?.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        definesPresentationContext = false

        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .top

    }
```

And add `SearchBarContainerView` class,

```
class SearchBarContainerView: UIView {  

    let searchBar: UISearchBar  

    init(customSearchBar: UISearchBar) {  
        searchBar = customSearchBar  
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)  

        addSubview(searchBar)  
    }

    override convenience init(frame: CGRect) {  
        self.init(customSearchBar: UISearchBar())  
        self.frame = frame  
    }  

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {  
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")  
    }  

    override func layoutSubviews() {  
        super.layoutSubviews()  
        searchBar.frame = bounds  
    }  
}
```

Following is working screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. it worked for me. I was also facing the same issue.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        searchbar.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
```

Comment: No it not works, Bro issue is when i clicked on SearchBar, Even i called `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or  even not called.

Comment: oh, for me issue was at load time. will look into your code an let u know.